# Android SwipeRefreshLayout - still a refresh button in the menu?

Tags: android

I am using the SwipeRefreshLayout in one of my views. When the view opens, it automatically does refresh and the user can see the SwipeRefreshLayout and should be able recognize it and know how to refresh the list at a later point.

I am not sure, whether I should I still put a refresh item in the menu or not.

Comment: What would bethe reason to refresh? i.e. changing search parameters, syncing data with a central store - bit more info please

Comment: The refresh would be to sync data by loading something from a website.

Answer (score 1):

I would not have a refresh button out in the open but I would add a Refresh option in the **[Action Overflow](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)** just in case user don't know about or forgets the swipe refresh action.  Sometimes redundancy is good because it acts as a safety net to cover all scenarios.

Many apps does this, here are some examples:

Android Email:

[image]

Google Play Newsstand:

[image]

Comment: helpful for accessibility users too - I don't think SwipeRefreshLayout exposes any talkback functionality to indicate that a swipe down at the top of the list will refresh.